# In Unity3D How to Detect the Collider Touch and Stay In Other Collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to check if the sphere collider still stay in the mesh collider.
now I used:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info)
{
    Debug.Log("enter");
}
void OnCollisionStay(Collision info)
{
    Debug.Log("stay");
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision info)
{
    Debug.Log("out");
}
```

here is the scene:

the onCollisionStay() will execute per frame ,but when the scene came to before,the Debug do not log continue,but the "Out".

So I need to Know Why the Stay event do not Stay and How to detect One Collider

Stay in the another just inside and touch?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of Sphere collider or use 'Delay' option in Collision Stay function. Your question is bit clumsy, What your are trying to do, tell it clearly.

Comment: the sphere is small like a point .when i move the sphere into the mesh collider,as I hope OnCollisionStay() should execute per frame ,but not.only log "stay" a few frames,nothing goes on

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details of the mesh collider? It might happen that the collider is pretty small also, and in some point, a part of the sphere (not the full sphere, so you think OnCollisionStay should still be called) goes out of the mesh collider, thus activating the OnCollisionExit(), but since the OnCollisionEnter() is not called back, OnCollisionStay() is never called again.

Maybe you can check that.